# WebGrid Asp.Net MVC Custom Pager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm try to extend my webgrid pager but when I try to call the method to page the system return me the follow error:

`System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid` does not contain a definition for `PagerList` and no extension method `PagerList` accepting a first argument of type `System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Look for my class constructor:

```
 public static HelperResult PagerList(
                this WebGrid webGrid,
                WebGridPagerModes mode = WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious | WebGridPagerModes.Numeric,
                string firstText = null,
                string previousText = null,
                string nextText = null,
                string lastText = null,
                int numericLinksCount = 5)
    {
        return PagerList(webGrid, mode, firstText, previousText, nextText, lastText, numericLinksCount, explicitlyCalled: true);
    }
```

Look for my Webgrid declaration and my extended class

```
var grdConvidados = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "deploymentsGrid", canSort: false, canPage:true);
    @grid.PagerList(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a namespace issue.  Can you show us namespace declarations for your code?

Answer (score 0):

Article describes the Efficient Paging with WebGrid Web Helper - ASP.NET MVC

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618

Thanks